# Show that a Lie algebra is solvable if and only if ideals $I$ and $L / I $ are solvable

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras

> Let $L$ be a finite dimensional Lie algebra than $L$ is semisimple if and only if any ideal $I$ and $L / I$ is semisimple.

I don't know much about solvable Lie algebra's besides some of the equivalent defintions.

Would appreciate any tips/help

Comment: Do you mean solvable and not semisimple? $I$ and $L/I$ being solvable is equivalent to $L$ being solvable.

Comment: @max That's indeed what I meant. I mixed up "solvable" and "semisimple".

Answer (score 1):

Let $g^i$ denote the Derived series, defined by $g^0=g$ and $g^i=[g^{i-1},g^{i-1}]$. Solvability is equivalent to the condition that there is $n$ such that $g^n=0$.

It is easy to check that $g^i/I=(g/I)^i$ and that $I^i\subseteq I\cap g^i$.

From this you see one side immediately. If say $g^n=0$, then $(g/I)^n=0/I=0$ and $I^n\subseteq g^n=0$. Thus solvability of $L$ implies solvability of $I$ and $L/I$.

For the other side, assume that $(g/I)^n=I^n=0$. As $(g/I)^n=g^n/I$ we see that $g^n\subseteq I$. As $J\subseteq I$ implies that $[J,J]\subseteq [I,I]$, we see inductively that $g^{2n}\subseteq I^n=0$.